# SQL sum of rows to create Total row

Tags: sql, database, sum, case, partitioning

Good afternoon, I have the following outputs in SQL and want a third row for each code adding:

[image]

I would like to add a total row as follows:

[image]

Thank you in advance. If you need the code I can provide that later.

```
DECLARE @FY_Ending INT
SET @FY_Ending = 2020

 SELECT
    CAST(DSS_CORPORATE.DBO.ODS_LOCAL_AUTHORITY_CODES.LA_CODE AS INT) AS CASSR_CODE
INTO
    #MAPPING
FROM
    DSS_CORPORATE.DBO.ODS_LOCAL_AUTHORITY_CODES
WHERE
    ORGANISATION_SUBTYPE_CODE IN ('A','E','H','J')
    AND BUSINESS_END_DATE IS NULL
    AND HIGH_LEVEL_HA_CODE <> 'Q99'
    AND LA_CODE <> '203' and LA_CODE <> '612' and LA_CODE <> '810' and LA_CODE <> '811'
    AND ((@FY_Ending < 2020 and LA_Code not in (738)) or (@FY_Ending >= 2020 and LA_Code not in (810,811)))

SELECT
    CASE    
        WHEN DATA.CASSR_CODE IS NULL THEN #MAPPING.CASSR_CODE
        ELSE DATA.CASSR_CODE
        END AS 'CASSR_CODE',    
        DATA.AgeBand_Key,
        SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_DIM_AGEBAND.AgeBand,
        DATA.COUNT
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_SOCC_SALT_FACT.CASSR_CODE,
        SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_SOCC_SALT_FACT.ItemType,
        SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_SOCC_SALT_FACT.AgeBand_Key,
        SUM(SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_SOCC_SALT_FACT.ItemValue) AS 'COUNT'
    FROM
        SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_SOCC_SALT_FACT
    WHERE
        SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_SOCC_SALT_FACT.FY_Ending = @FY_Ending
        AND SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_SOCC_SALT_FACT.ClientType_Key = 1
        AND SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_SOCC_SALT_FACT.AgeBand_Key IN (2,3)
        AND SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_SOCC_SALT_FACT.SequelToSupportRequest_Key IS NOT NULL
        AND SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_SOCC_SALT_FACT.SequelToSupportRequest_Key <> 7
    GROUP BY
        SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_SOCC_SALT_FACT.CASSR_CODE,
        SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_SOCC_SALT_FACT.ItemType,
        SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_SOCC_SALT_FACT.AgeBand_Key) DATA

LEFT JOIN SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_DIM_AGEBAND ON DATA.AgeBand_Key = SOCC_SALT.IC.V3_DIM_AGEBAND.AgeBand_KEY
FULL OUTER JOIN #MAPPING ON DATA.CASSR_CODE = #MAPPING.CASSR_CODE

Order by 1,4 asc


DROP TABLE #MAPPING
```

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  You might also include the query that is generating these results.

Comment: In MSSQL you can use [ROLLUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), in MySQL you can use [ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html), In PostgreSQL you can use [ROLLUP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS).

Comment: in Oracle or MSSQL you can use `group By Grouping sets` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumming that you r sample data is a table, you could get the totals using pure sql like this:

```
select CASSR_CODE, AgeBand_Key, AgeBand, [count] from your_sample_table
union all
select CASSR_CODE, 4 as AgeBand_Key, 'Total' as AgeBand, sum([count])
from your_sample_table
group by CASSR_CODE
order by CASSR_CODE, AgeBand_Key
```

Depending on your DBMS, there are other better choices in the links shared by @Luuk

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL you can use [ROLLUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15),

in MySQL you can use [ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html),

In PostgreSQL you can use [ROLLUP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS).